# Java Spring Mongo, ignore case in sorting while fetching data using repositories, MongoRepository and QueryDslPredicateExecutor

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

I am using below code to fetch data from mongo using repository:

```
BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();

booleanBuilder
    .and(QMyClass.myClass.account.eq(987654321l));

Page<MyClass> myClassPage = myClassRepository
    .findAll(booleanBuilder, new PageRequest(0, 20, Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"));
```

or

```
myClassRepository.findByAccount(987654321l, new PageRequest(0, 20, Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"))
```

with both setup, I get results in below "name" sort order, first sorted lower case then uppercase:

```
mary
john
andrew
Mary
Anil
1Sam
```

I want the result without considering case.

I am already aware that I can use  custom query and use Collation with mongotemplate. I want to know whether I can use it with repositories with my existing setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no collation support in repositories. For now, to solve this I created one more column that stores only lowercase and then apply sort/search on this new column.

Answer (score 2):

I've added a [feature request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1854) to add the collation support for the repository. I'll update to answer to include example when the feature request is implemented.